# Compare three columns of two tables Laravel Controller

Tags: database, laravel

Im trying to compare two columns of two tables. I've been comparing them in blade but it get slows loading my site, so I want to work in my controller.

This is my view:

```
@foreach ($events as $event)
@foreach ($goals as $goal)

@if($event->goalsHome == $goal->home
and $event->goalsDraw == $goal->draw
and $event->goalsAway == $goal->away)

@endif
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

But i want to pass to my controller and I have something like this:

```
    public function index()
    {        

        $home = DB::table('goals')->select('home')->where('status','1')->get();
        $draw = DB::table('goals')->select('draw')->where('status','1')->get();
        $away = DB::table('goals')->select('away')->where('status','1')->get();

        $events = DB::table('data')
                ->where('goalsHome' ,'=', $home)
                ->where('goalsDraw' ,'=', $draw)
                ->where('goalsAway' ,'=', $away)
                ->get();
        //return view('results')->with(compact('events'));  

        dd($events);
    }
}
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

How to fix this and what suggestions you do. Thanks in advance.

So now Im using another logic but it shows 0 items: (the data are numbers with dots, fe: 7.60, 8.00, 1.24)

```
    public function index()
    {        

$goals= DB::table('goals')->where('status','1')->get();
 foreach($goals as $goal) 
             {
             $eventHome[]=$goal->home;
             $eventDraw[]=$goal->draw;
             $eventAway[]=$goal->away;
             }

$homes = DB::table('data')->where('goalsHome','=', $eventHome)->where('goalsDraw','=', $eventDraw)->where('goalsAway','=', $eventAway)->get();   

dd($homes);

}
```

Comment: Because when you use get function then it will retrieve multiple row from database and it will store the data on variable as a array. So when you try to compare this value it gives a error..

Comment: Can you help me with the best way to achieve what im trying?

Comment: You have to give me screenshot of your goals table from database... I have to show the data/rows.. The i will try to help you

Comment: The content of the columns are decimals, they are for example: 7.00, 10.00, 2.05, etc.

Comment: see my answer and give the outputs of dd()...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$events = Data::all();
 foreach($events as $event) 
             {
             $eventlist[]=$event->goalsHome;
             }
//dd($eventlist)//first perform this dd() 
$home = DB::table('goals')->select('home')->where('status','1')->get();   
            foreach($homes as $home) 
             {//getting all the teams who already played in first round
             $list[]=$home->home;
}
//dd($list);//comment out first dd() , then test this dd()
```

by using thgis array method you can check/compare

```
if(in_array($eventlist,$list)) {
//your login goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Im getting this error: ```syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)```

Comment: in dd($eventlist) i forgot to add semicolon did you give this?

Comment: Both are working, $eventlist shows the data 'oddsHome from 'data' table, and $list shows all the data 'home' from 'goals' table, but i need to compare with draw and away!

Comment: Doing that, Am I doing the same as i was doing first in my view? I want to show on my blade just the matches that have the same data in those three columns of each table

Comment: if by dd() you are getting the answer then you can pass this variable also in blade as you always do to show the tables.

Comment: $tips = DB::table('goals')->where('status','1')->get();
 foreach($tips as $goal) 
             {
             $eventHome[]=$goal->home;
             $eventDraw[]=$goal->draw;
             $eventAway[]=$goal->away;
             }

Comment: and yes you have to first get the apidata table data like goals table..then you can compare. also You cant mention names.remember it.Either i cannot help you.

Comment: Seems that it is kinda hard to solve the problem by this way. Any way to contact you so we can talk better?. Anyways im marking your answer like the best one.

Comment: The data that i want to compare are numbers with dot: for example: 7.00, 8.50, 10.01

Comment: if you cant figure it out then tell all the details what you actually want and give me the model,controller and view info and database records. I will try to solve it. And please remove my names from your post

Answer (score 0):

When you call your table like so, it will return an object and not the single column value. Therefor you try to put in your result, it will find and object instead of a string therefor you get that error.

```
// will return stdClass with the format {"goals": 2}
$home = DB::table('goals')->select('home')->where('status','1')->get();
```

Therefor if you change your logic like so, your logic should work.

```
$events = DB::table('data')
    ->where('goalsHome' ,'=', $home->home)
    ->where('goalsDraw' ,'=', $draw->draw)
    ->where('goalsAway' ,'=', $away->away)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. It gets my this error: Property [home] does not exist on this collection instance.